# Measure correlation between a time series of xy points - python

Tags: python, pandas, synchronization

I'm aiming to return a single **continuous** measurement describing the synchrony between a time series of xy points. Using below, there are two separate points (`A,B`). They are moving in a similar direction for the first 3 time steps and in diverging directions for the last 3 time steps.

In essence, they are following the same direction for time steps `1-3` and then diverge to move in completely separate directions in time steps `4-6`

There are a few options when measuring the synchrony between a single time series in isolation (either the x-coordinate or y-coordinate). But I can't find a function or algorithm that accounts for both axes (both x and y).

I can use `pearsonr` or a `crosscorr` function but it would have to measure the x or y-axis independently. Not the xy coordinate together.

Could I use the angle of movement? I'm hoping the intended output can be appended to the data frame at each point in time that represents the synchronisation of moving points.

**Note: I'm hoping to output will be continuous and numerical (float makes most sense). I have inserted two distinct options below. However points can be moving in a similar direction (but not identical) or in completely divergent paths. The output should handle this.**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6],    
    'Label' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
    'x' : [-2.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0],
    'y' : [-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,-3.0,0.0,-4.0,1.0,-5.0,2.0],              
   })

x = df.groupby('Label')['x'].diff().fillna(0).astype(float)
y = df.groupby('Label')['y'].diff().fillna(0).astype(float) 

# Return rotation of scalar difference and convert angle
df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(x, y)
df['Angle'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])

df_A = df[df['Label'] == 'A'].reset_index(drop = True)
df_B = df[df['Label'] == 'B'].reset_index(drop = True)

#rolling_corr = df_A['Angle'].rolling(1).corr(df_B['Angle'])
#print(rolling_corr)

r, p = stats.pearsonr(df_A['Angle'], df_B['Angle'])
print(f"Scipy computed Pearson r: {r} and p-value: {p}")
```

Intended output:

```
    Time Label    x    y  Rotation  Angle Corr
0      1     A -2.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0 1.0
1      1     B -1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0 1.0
2      2     A -1.0 -2.0  1.570796   90.0 1.0
3      2     B  0.0 -1.0  1.570796   90.0 1.0
4      3     A  0.0 -2.0  1.570796   90.0 1.0
5      3     B  1.0 -1.0  1.570796   90.0 1.0
6      4     A  0.0 -3.0  3.141593  180.0 0.0
7      4     B  1.0  0.0  0.000000    0.0 0.0
8      5     A  0.0 -4.0  3.141593  180.0 0.0
9      5     B  1.0  2.0  0.000000    0.0 0.0
10     6     A  0.0 -5.0  3.141593  180.0 0.0
11     6     B  1.0  1.0  3.141593  180.0 0.0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? `They are in sync for the first 3 time points` - what (quantitatively) do you mean in this statement?

Comment: I can't make sense of your question :/

Comment: Meaning they are moving in exactly the same direction/angular velocity.

Comment: I'm not following you there... In your comment you are definitely stating that you want the same 'exact' direction. And in your other comment (on my answer), you are refering to some kind of tolerance and of insensibility to the oriented direction (meaning you want to return True/1 in steps 4,5,6, though you stated in your question that your points are "out of sync" in those same steps). What do you really want ?

Comment: I apologise, this was meant for @anonn01. I emphasised _exact_ to explain the synchronisation. I'll elucidate in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I got this right.

If I follow your example, your points are considered synchrones if their trajectory is the same between steps.

If this is it, I'do it this way (note that you made a mistake about the [arctan2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) function, it is expecting Y args first).

```
df[['move_x', 'move_y']] = df.groupby('Label')[['x', 'y']].diff().fillna(0)
df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(df['move_y'], df['move_x'])
df['Angle'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])

temp = df.pivot_table('Angle', index="Time", columns="Label")
temp['same_direction'] = temp.eq(temp.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)
temp.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df = df.join(temp)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df.drop(['move_x', 'move_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Returns :

```
    Time Label    x    y  Rotation  Angle  same_direction
0      1     A -2.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0            True
1      1     B -1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0            True
2      2     A -1.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0            True
3      2     B  0.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0            True
4      3     A  0.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0            True
5      3     B  1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0            True
6      4     A  0.0 -3.0 -1.570796  -90.0           False
7      4     B  1.0  0.0  1.570796   90.0           False
8      5     A  0.0 -4.0 -1.570796  -90.0           False
9      5     B  1.0  1.0  1.570796   90.0           False
10     6     A  0.0 -5.0 -1.570796  -90.0           False
11     6     B  1.0  2.0  1.570796   90.0           False
```

**EDIT**

As I stated earlier, I'm not following you on those comments. But if you want to stick with directions in the [0;pi[ quadrant and a add a tolerance of one degree divergence, I think you could alter the process this way :

```
df[['move_x', 'move_y']] = df.groupby('Label')[['x', 'y']].diff().fillna(0)
df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(df['move_y'], df['move_x'])
df['Angle'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])


temp = df.pivot_table('Rotation', index="Time", columns="Label")

#get back in the [0;pi[ quadrant :
temp = np.abs(temp).replace(np.pi, 0)

temp['MeanAngle'] = np.arctan2(np.mean(np.sin(temp), axis=1), np.mean(np.cos(temp), axis=1)) #compute mean angle at each step
temp = np.degrees(temp) #convert to degrees

THRESHOLD = .5 #tolerance of 1 degree equals to a tolerance to .5 degree to the mean angle
temp['ALMOST_SYNC'] = False
ix = temp[
    (np.abs(temp.MeanAngle - temp.A < THRESHOLD))
    & (np.abs(temp.MeanAngle - temp.B < THRESHOLD))
    ].index
temp.loc[ix, 'ALMOST_SYNC'] = True

temp.drop(['A', 'B', 'MeanAngle'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df = df.join(temp)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df.drop(['move_x', 'move_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

returns

```
    Time Label    x    y  Rotation  Angle  ALMOST_SYNC
0      1     A -2.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0         True
1      1     B -1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0         True
2      2     A -1.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0         True
3      2     B  0.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0         True
4      3     A  0.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0         True
5      3     B  1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0         True
6      4     A  0.0 -3.0 -1.570796  -90.0         True
7      4     B  1.0  0.0  1.570796   90.0         True
8      5     A  0.0 -4.0 -1.570796  -90.0         True
9      5     B  1.0  1.0  1.570796   90.0         True
10     6     A  0.0 -5.0 -1.570796  -90.0         True
11     6     B  1.0  2.0  1.570796   90.0         True
```

**EDIT 2:**

For some kind of linear metric, you could use the max delta on all angles and the mean angle (having two points, this will be equivalent to the min, btw) :

```
df[['move_x', 'move_y']] = df.groupby('Label')[['x', 'y']].diff().fillna(0)
df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(df['move_y'], df['move_x'])
df['Angle'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])


temp = df.pivot_table('Rotation', index="Time", columns="Label")

#get back in the [0;pi[ quadrant :
temp = np.abs(temp).replace(np.pi, 0)

cols = temp.columns.tolist()

temp['MeanAngle'] = np.arctan2(np.mean(np.sin(temp), axis=1), np.mean(np.cos(temp), axis=1)) #compute mean angle at each step
temp = np.degrees(temp) #convert to degrees

temp['MAX_DELTA'] = np.max(
        (np.array([np.abs(temp[f] - temp['MeanAngle']) for f in cols]).T),
        axis=1)

temp.drop(['A', 'B', 'MeanAngle'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df = df.join(temp)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df.drop(['move_x', 'move_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Returns :

```
    Time Label    x    y  Rotation  Angle  MAX_DELTA
0      1     A -2.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
1      1     B -1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
2      2     A -1.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
3      2     B  0.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
4      3     A  0.0 -2.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
5      3     B  1.0 -1.0  0.000000    0.0        0.0
6      4     A  0.0 -3.0 -1.570796  -90.0        0.0
7      4     B  1.0  0.0  1.570796   90.0        0.0
8      5     A  0.0 -4.0 -1.570796  -90.0        0.0
9      5     B  1.0  1.0  1.570796   90.0        0.0
10     6     A  0.0 -5.0 -1.570796  -90.0        0.0
11     6     B  1.0  2.0  1.570796   90.0        0.0
```

Comment: In essence. But I'm hoping to return something more continuous than True/False or 0-1. For instance, the points could be moving in opposite direction or there could be one degree difference. Yet both would return False. I'm hoping the resulting output can handle this.

Comment: Just added some hints of how to proceed in that case. Hopes this help.

Comment: It does but I'm hoping the output will be continuous. Not a discrete output of 0 or 1, True or False. Even though a tolerance adds flexibility, you still have to pass some arbitrary threshold value. Similar to a correlation. It's not 0 or 1. A correlation of 0.8 is still strong compared to 0.3. I'm reluctant to pass and arbitrary value where everything above x if synced. Does the question make sense now?

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to understand. Though I'm not sure SO is the right place to ask if you don't have a precise metric in mind in the first place (there is more theory behind that question that algorithm)... My last update gives you a continuous deviation value, that is a score of the delta (in degrees) between the main angle and the direction of each point. You could also divide it by 180 if you want the metric to be in the [0;1] segment. But whatever the metric you will be using, you will finally have to choose a threshold to classify your "sync" label...

Comment: I didn't mean to push the 'in sync' statement so hard. I just want to continual metric here. I can worry about the threshold value later. For now I'm just hoping for a continuous output that records the similarity/synchronization/correlation in orientation/direction between two points.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Is there something wrong with the "delta metric" I provided or does this answer your need ? It *is* continuous and does not depend of the opposites directions (in fact, it should stick to 0 when there is exact sync, up to 45 (and not 180 as I previously stated) when there is a complete divergence). So if you want a metric with 1 for perfect correlation, you could replace it by `1-df['MAX_DELTA']/45`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure directional correlation between two sets of points, it's probably best to use dot products. You can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). For example, try:

```py
# Example Values
A_prime = [0, 0]
A = [1, 2]
B_prime = [3, 7]
B = [2, 9]

delta_A = [A[0] - A_prime[0], A[1] - A_prime[1]]
delta_B = [B[0] - B_prime[0], B[1] - B_prime[1]]

similarity = delta_A[0] * delta_B[0] + delta_A[1] * delta_B[1]  
# dot product similarity measure
print(similarity)
```

Pandas may also have a built-in way to implement the dot product much faster. Ideally, you should be able to calculate the dot product for each pair of A, B values and get the table that you had in your example.